# SOSL and returned fields

Tags: apex, sosl

In SOQL, if you don't specify the returned fields and then try to query them, you get an error. Is it the same in SOSL?

```
List<List<sObject>> values = [FIND 'acme' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account, Opportunity(id, name)];

List <Account> a = values.get(0);
String name = a.get(0).name; // will this line produce an error since we did not specify the name field in the SOSL query
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll get this error whenever you try to access a field you did not retrieve via SOSL/SOQL.

Comment: Only exception would be this. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160112/sobjectexception-no-more-intentional-change

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Right, but it's a bug. It should ordinarily throw an exception.